# CoreData: Query to one-to-many-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

I have a core data model like this:

[image]

and I'm trying to query all the movies showing a theater with particular schedule.

But I can not figure out how can I this query with NSPredicate.

I tried this:

```
NSPredicate *moviesPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY (movies, $x, $x.movies.showTimes == %@ AND  $x.movies.theater.nameOfTheater == %@).@count >0", showTime, theater];
```

but didn't work. Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong?

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming from your stated objective ("... query all the movies showing a theater with particular schedule") that the entity for your NSFetchRequest is `Movies`.  If so, the attribute and relationship names you use should all be relative to that entity.  Hence the theatre name will be given by `theaters.nameOfTheater` and the show times will be `showTimes.showTimes`.  Because there are many `Schedules` for a given `Movie`, your predicate needs to select a movie if ANY of the `showTimes.showTimes` match your requirement.  So one way to write the predicate would be:

```
NSPredicate *moviesPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"theaters.nameOfTheater == %@ AND (ANY showTimes.showTimes == %@)", theater, showTime];
```

Alternatively, the ANY clause can be rewritten as a SUBQUERY:

```
NSPredicate *moviesPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"theaters.nameOfTheater == %@ AND SUBQUERY(showTimes, $x, $x.showTimes == %@).@count > 0", theater, showTime];
```

As a broader recommendation, I would make some changes the names of your attributes and entities; it will help to make things clearer:

1. Entity names should generally be singular, so `Movie` not `Movies`, `Theatre` not `Theatres` and `Schedule` not `Schedules`.
2. Likewise the names of relationships should reflect whether they are to-one or to-many.  So the Movie entity should have a relationship `theatre` since it is to-one, and the Schedule entity should have a relationship `movies` since it is to-many.

Finally, I think you could improve your data model.  Currently, each Movie can have only one Theater.  In practice, I would imagine that a movie will be shown at more than one theater!  Personally, I would have a model like this:

[image: Data Model]

So each `Schedule` relates to only one `Movie` and one `Theater`.  But each `Theater` has many `showings`, and each `Movie` has many `screenings`.  Using this model, the predicate to meet your query would be:

```
NSPredicate *moviesPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(screenings, $x, $x.theater.nameOfTheater == %@ AND $x.showTime == %@).@count > 0", theater, showTime];
```